# datetimefield only show time in html template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a datetime field but in the html code I would like to show only the time, how can I do?
I tried {{ data|time }}, {{ value|time:"H:i" }} but nothing

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Count
import datetime

# Create your views here.

def contatore(request):
    settaggio = Count.objects.get(attivo = True)
    data = settaggio.data.strftime("%m %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")

    context = {'data':data}
    return render(request, 'count.html', context)
```

models

```
class Count(models.Model):

    data = models.DateTimeField()
```

html

```
<h5 style="color: #fff">{{ data }}</h5>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter in your template like this:

```
<h5 style="color: #fff">{{ data|date:"H, i, s" }}</h5>
```

views py:

```
def contatore(request):
   settaggio = Count.objects.get(attivo = True)
   context = {'data':settaggio.data}
   return render(request, 'count.html', context)
```

Comment: no nothing does not show me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{ data |date:"g:i a" }}
```

Comment: no nothing does not show me